# Reliably splitting lines out of a string

Tags: c, string, networking

I'm writing myself a small server daemon in C, and the basic parts like processing connects, disconnects and receives are already in, but a problem in receiving still persists.

I use "recv" to read 256 bytes at once into a char array, and because it can contain multiple lines of data as one big chunk, I need to be able to split each line separatly to process it.
That alone wouldn't be the problem, but because of the possibility that a line could be cut off because it didn't fit into the buffer anymore, I also need to be able to see if a line has been cut off. Not that bad, too, just check the last char for `\r` or `\n`, but what **if** the line was cut off? My code does not allow for easy "just keep reading more data" because I'm using `select()` to handle multiple requests.

Basically, this is my situation:

```
//This is the chunk of code ran after select(), when a socket
//has readable data
char buf[256] = { 0 };
int nbytes;

if ((nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0)) <= 0)
{   
   if (nbytes == 0)
   {   
      struct remote_address addr;

      get_peername(i, &addr);
      do_log("[Socket #%d] %s:%d disconnected", i, addr.ip, addr.port);
   }   
   else
      do_log("recv(): %s", strerror(errno));

   close(i);
   FD_CLR(i, &clients);
}   
else
{   
   buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;
   struct remote_address addr;

   get_peername(i, &addr);
   do_log("[Socket #%d] %s:%d (%d bytes): %s", i, addr.ip, addr.port, nbytes, buf);

   // split "buf" here, and process each line
   // but how to be able to get the rest of a possibly cut off line
   // in case it did not fit into the 256 byte buffer?
}
```

I was thinking about having a higher scoped temporary buffer variable (possibly `malloc()`'d) to save the current buffer in, if it was too long to fit in at once, but I always feel bad about introducing unnecessarily high scoped variables if there's a better solution :/

I appreciate any pointers (*except for the XKCD ones :)*)!

Comment: void* ptr = &ptr;  // Here's a pointer

Comment: That falls under "XKCD ones": http://xkcd.com/138/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to add another per-stream buffer that holds the incomplete line until the line feed that comes after is received.

Comment: indeed, if you add backspace handling, you could make ur app work with hyperterminal too since user are allowed to undo their typo

Comment: This is the standard way of doing things (you can do the `read` straight into this per-stream buffer).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some kind of dynamically expanding buffer like [GString](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html) to accumulate data.

The other thing that might help would be putting the socket into nonblocking mode using `fcntl()`. Then you can `recv()` in a loop until you get a -1. Check `errno`, it will be either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` (and those aren't required to have the same value: check for both).

Final remark: I found that using libev (google it; I can't post multiple links) was more fun than using `select()`.